# Azure custom domain will only resolve via www subdomain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've got a Google-managed domain that I'm trying to point to an Azure-hosted web application. Currently, the request works fine through the www subdomain, but when connecting through the root domain I get the error " refuses to connect." I'm not sure which piece I'm missing in the DNS records. My desired end result is to have both root and www resolve to the root domain, while forcing https. The certificate is managed through Azure and functions fine through the www subdomain.

Here are the current records:

| Host name | Type | TTL | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| domain.com | A | 1 hour | xx.xx.xxx.xx (found in Azure custom domain page) |
| domain.com | TXT | 1 hour | "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" |
| asuid.domain.com | TXT | 1 hour | "OWNERSHIPVERIFICATIONCODE" |
| asuid.www.domain.com | TXT | 1 hour | "OWNERSHIPVERIFICATIONCODE" |
| [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) | CNAME | 1 hour | myazuresubdomain.azurewebsites.net |

I have verified all the values that are censored, and they are correct according to the various documentation pages. I believe my www subdomain is only connecting because it's a CNAME record pointing to the azure subdomain, and that there's something missing when connecting to the IP in the A record (which I have copied and pasted and verified multiple times).

I have seen some solutions about forwarding the root to the www subdomain, but I can't get that to work, either.

I also have a few SendGrid records, but I do not believe they overlap with any of these listed.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

> For this issue, you need add an A record for the root domain that points to the same IP address as the CNAME record for the www subdomain. This allows you to connect to the root domain as well as the www subdomain.

**Steps to point your Google-managed domain to an Azure-hosted web application**.

1. Sign into the website of your domain provider.
2. Check the page for managing DNS records, Domain Name, DNS, or Name Server Management.
3. Create a DNS record and select the DNS record type based on the Domain validation section in the Azure (CNAME, A, or TXT).
4. Configure the DNS record based on the Host and Value columns from the Domain validation section in Azure.
5. And make sure to add two different records for your custom domain.
6. To redirect the root domain to the `www subdomain`, you can create a `URL Redirect or URL` Forward entry in your `DNS settings`.

Sample DNS records:

| Host Name | Type | TTL DATA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| domain.com | `A` | 1 hour xx.xx.xxx.xx (found in Azure custom domain page) |
| domain.com | `TXT"` | 1 hour "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" |
| asuid.domain.com | `TXT` | TXT 1 hour "OWNERSHIPVERIFICATIONCODE" |
| asuid.www.domain.com | `TXT` | TXT 1 hour "OWNERSHIPVERIFICATIONCODE" |
| www.domain.com | `CNAME` | CNAME 1 hour myazuresubdomain.azurewebsites.net |
| domain.com | `A` | 1 hour xx.xx.xxx.xx (same IP address as the CNAME record for www) |

To set up a custom domain with `Azure DNS` in `Azure Static Web Apps`, you need to use Azure DNS to manage your domain name for [Azure Static Web Apps](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/custom-domain-azure-dns.md#create-dns-records-in-azure-dns).

In the Validate + Configure tab, enter the following values:

- Domain name: This value should match the domain name you entered in the previous step (with the www subdomain).
- Hostname record type: Select `CNAME`.

If you want to point your DNS zone apex to Azure CDN endpoints, you can use [alias records](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/dns/dns-alias.md).

Custom domain

[image]

Check this for  [custom domain and a managed certificate.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/tutorial-secure-domain-certificate.md)

Comment: Thank you, Rajesh. These steps are all looking like what I have done. Someone else asked me to try it from my phone without wifi on, and it works perfectly--I can't explain the difference. It's not a propagation issue because I've had these settings for months. I've flushed the DNS and it still doesn't work.